# Bukkit - other class Error

Tags: java, bukkit

I do have an issue with my plugin I am creating. when I want to have organized classes I tried to put them in other classes but it still doesn't work. so I need help from someone.

The error is: http://pastebin.com/cYXygQZe

But I think I have everything but I do not know what I am missing.

Main class (called: heal.java):

```js
package me.hoopless;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class heal extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{

 public void onEnable(){
  System.out.print("Hai");
  getCommand("ts3").setExecutor(new information(this));
  getCommand("heal").setExecutor(new healc(this));
 }
 
}
```

Second Class (healc.java):

```js
package me.hoopless;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class healc extends JavaPlugin implements CommandExecutor, Listener{

 heal plugin;
 
 public healc(heal passedplugin){
  this.plugin = passedplugin;
 }
 public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args){
  
  String prefix = ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "[" + ChatColor.AQUA + "Server" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "] ";
  
  Player player = (Player) sender;
  
  if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("heal") || cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("eat") && sender instanceof Player){
   
   
   
   // /healplayer 1 2 3
   
 
   int length = args.length;
    
    if (length == 0){
     player.setHealth(20.0);
     player.setFoodLevel(20);
     player.sendMessage(prefix + ChatColor.GRAY + "Your health has been updated");
    }else if (length == 1){
     
     boolean playerFound = false;
     
     for (Player playerToHeal : Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers()){
      if (playerToHeal.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(args[0])){
       playerToHeal.setHealth(20.0);
       playerToHeal.setFoodLevel(20);
       playerToHeal.sendMessage(prefix + ChatColor.GRAY + "You have been healed by " +ChatColor.RED + player.getName());
       player.sendMessage(prefix + ChatColor.RED + playerToHeal.getName() + ChatColor.GRAY +" Was healed.");
       playerFound = true;
       break;
      }
     }
     if (playerFound == false){
      player.sendMessage(prefix + ChatColor.RED + args[0] + ChatColor.GRAY + " was not found!");
     }
    } else player.sendMessage(prefix + ChatColor.GRAY + "Command typed incorrectly.");
     
    
   
   
   return true;
  }
  
  return false;
 }
}
```

Third class (information.java):

```js
package me.hoopless;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class information extends JavaPlugin implements CommandExecutor, Listener{

 heal plugin;
 public information(heal passedplugin){
  this.plugin = passedplugin;
 }
  @Override
  public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args){
    
   String prefix = ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "[" + ChatColor.AQUA + "Server" + ChatColor.DARK_GRAY + "] ";
   Player player = (Player) sender;
   
   if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ts3"))
    player.sendMessage(prefix +ChatColor.GRAY + "Our Teamspeak IP is: " + ChatColor.AQUA + "ts3.server.net");
    
    return false;
   }
  }
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: [Don't use JS snippets for Java, they're not the same thing.](http://javascriptisnotjava.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Only 1 class can extend JavaPlugin, you have every one extending it.

Also some other fixes:

- You can do Bukkit#getPlayer and check if it's null rather than you looping through all players and having a boolean.
- Don't cast Player without checking if sender is an instance of Player, it can be console which would make that throw an error.